# Why intern method does not return equal String in java

Tags: java

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    String s1 = new String("hello");
    String s2 = new String("hello");
    s1.intern();
    s2.intern();        
    System.out.println(s1 == s2); // why this returns false ?


}
```

as per my understanding, 1st call to intern method should have created a 'string intern pool' with a single string `"hello"`. second call to intern method would have done nothing (as `"hello"` string is already present in pool). Now, when i say `s1 == s2` i am expecting JVM to compare `"hello"` string from string intern pool and return `true`.

Comment: Wow answers were ready, just waiting all for site to come back in write mode.

Comment: As you aren't comparing the value returned by String.intern(), your expectations of how this comparison should work are wholly lacking in basis.

Comment: Just because it's a question about String.intern doesn't mean it's a dup. In this case the OP thought that intern had an effect on the string it was called on. The other question is a completely different question on String.intern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `intern()` method does **not modify** the string, it simply **returns** the corresponding string from the string pool. So, since you're not keeping the return values, your calls to `intern()` are meaningless. However, if you actually use them, you'll see that both point to exactly the same string:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String s1 = new String("hello");
    String s2 = new String("hello");
    s1 = s1.intern();
    s2 = s2.intern();        
    System.out.println(s1 == s2); // will print true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are just checking on the original strings that refer to different objects in the heap.
You are not storing the returned value of [String#intern()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) method.

It should be

```
String s1 = new String("hello");
String s2 = new String("hello");
String s11 = s1.intern();
String s22 = s2.intern();
System.out.println(s11 == s22); // returns true
```

Answer (score 3):

[`String.intern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern--) *returns* a new interned string. To change `s1` and `s2` you do

```
s1 = s1.intern();
s2 = s2.intern();
```

`s1 == s2` will then return true.

Answer (score 1):

Its actually string property that you need to assign the value after calling these method, Lets take an example even if:

```
String S1= "Hello";
S1.concat("World");
```

and if you print the value of S1 it will print only "Hello". but if you write like this:

```
S1=S1.concat(" World");
```

then it will print "Hello World".

Similarly you need to assign the value as:

```
s1=s1.intern();
s2=s2.intern();
```

and if you compare s1==s2 it will return true value but, Lets say:

```
String s3=s1.intern();
String s4=s2.intern();
```

and if you compare s3==s4 then its true but (s3==s1) and (s4==s2) are false.